# Second part of if statement doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
if(($(this).val().length == 0) && ($(this).not('.optionalField'))){
```

The second part of this statement does not work (after &&). Does anybody know why?
Only one field in my form has class optionalField, but for some reason it treats all fields the same??? Is this code wrong?

Comment: Please check if it contains class or something , just not may not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably meant to use [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) instead of `.not()` which filters the current result set against the intersection of the `.optionalfield` selector:

```
!$(this).is('.optionalField')
```

So:

```
if ($(this).val().length == 0 && !$(this).is('.optionalField')) {
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be a better solution (the `!` implying "not" [`hasClass`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) )

`if(($(this).val().length == 0) && ( !$(this).hasClass('optionalField'))){`

`.not()` was traditionally used for other properties (`:checked`, `:visible`, etc.)